# How to write a function that returns a speciic function

Tags: r, function

I want to write a function that returns a function, similar to `approxfun`.

Consider, we have the following initialization:

```
x <- 5:10
y <- x^2
```

Specifically, I want to write a function with the following header:

```
generate_function <- function(x, y)
```

The function that is returned should have the following header:

```
function(new_x)
```

The returned value should be the result of

```
if (new_data >= min(x) & (new_data <= max(x) {
  fm <- loess(y ~ x)
  return(predict(fm, newdata = data.frame(x = new_x)))
} else return(<some_other_value>)
```

I hope I made my goal understable. Somehow I couldn't figure out a way how to do it. Can anyone help me with this? This would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance and best greetings,
Sebastian

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking but it explains how to create functions which return other functions in the [closures](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures) section of the functional programming chapter of Advanced R by Hadley Wickham.

Comment: You have `new_data` but then want to predict for `x=5`? Not for `x=new_data`? And `left, right` are never used.

Comment: @RuiBarrades: Thanks for pointing out that `x` and `y` weren't used - I originally had something in mind I wanted to do with them!

Comment: @SamR: Thanks for the helpful pointer - this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Just return the function. That is called closure.

```
generate_function <- function(x, y, left, right) {
  function(new_data) {
    if (new_data >= min(x) & (new_data <= max(x))) {
      fm <- loess(y ~ x)
      return(predict(fm, newdata = data.frame(x = new_data)))
    } else return(NA)
  }
}

f <- generate_function(x, y, 3, 4)
f(7)
# 1 
#49
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this incredibly fast and helpful answer!

This solves the problem for me!